# "is not accessible you might not have permission" message when accessing a password protected share folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, file-sharing

I'm sharing a password protected folder from my Windows 7, but the other computer which is using Windows Vista is unable to access this folder. This Vista can access my other **non** password protected shared folders without any problem. But when trying to access the password protected one, it says the folder is "is not accessible".

Here are the things I've tried:

- turned of the firewall on both PCs.
- turned on network discovery, file and printer sharing, turn off password sharing, disabled homegroup connection.
- I tried to turn on password sharing as well, it gives the same error.
- try to create the same username and password on the Vista.

So, what else I can try?

Comment: Does the Vista user have an account on the Windows 7 box?

Comment: Are they logging on with a local account on the computer sharing the files?

Comment: @MoifMurphy, I'm not sure what you mean by Windows 7 box, so I guess I don't have it.

Comment: @StephenMartin, no, they can see the folder without logging in, but is not prompted for password either when trying to access the folder.